# Event Delegation, need for the row number to show up on the added items

Tags: javascript

I need for the row number to show up on the added items to the list

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript &amp; jQuery - Chapter 7: Introducing jQuery - 
Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c7.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
  <h1 id="header">List</h1>
  <h2>Buy groceries <span id="counter"></span></h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="Row: 1" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
    <li id="Row: 2" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
    <li id="Row: 3" class="hot">honey</li>
    <li id="Row: 4">balsamic vinegar</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">new item</button>
</div>
  <form id="newItemForm">
    <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add description" />
    <input type="submit" id="add" value="add" />
  </form>
</div>
<script src="js/jq.js"></script>
<script src="js/ex.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Js

```
$(function() {
var ids = '';
var $listItems = $('li');

$listItems.on('mouseover click', function() {
ids = this.id;
$listItems.children('span').remove();
$(this).append(' <span class="priority">' + ids + '</span>');
});

$listItems.on('mouseout', function() {
$(this).children('span').remove();
});

});

$(function() {
var $list, $newItemForm, $newItemButton;
var item = '';                                 
$list = $('ul');                               
$newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');              
$newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');          

$('li').hide().each(function(index) {          
$(this).delay(450 * index).fadeIn(1600);     
});

function updateCount() {                       
var items = $('li[class!=complete]').length; 
$('#counter').text(items);                   
}
updateCount();                                

$newItemButton.show();                         
$newItemForm.hide();                           
$('#showForm').on('click', function() {       
$newItemButton.hide();                       
$newItemForm.show();                         
});

$newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {       
e.preventDefault();                         
var text = $('input:text').val();           
$list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');      
$('input:text').val('');                    
updateCount();                              
 });

$list.on('click', 'li', function() {
var $this = $(this);               
var complete = $this.hasClass('complete');  

if (complete === true) {          
  $this.animate({                  
    opacity: 0.0,
    paddingLeft: '+=180'
  }, 500, 'swing', function() {    
    $this.remove();                
  });
} else {                          
  item = $this.text();             
  $this.remove();                 
  $list                            
    .append('<li class=\"complete\">' + item + '</li>')
    .hide().fadeIn(300);           
  updateCount();                   
}                                  
});                                 

});
```

When you hover your mouse over the rows, the row number would appear trailing
(appear after) the text of that row. After the mouse leaves the row, the row number should disappear. The “NEW ITEM” button in the example let you insert new rows. After new rows are inserted, you need to make sure the effect you implemented above works for the newly added rows also.

You can view my page here: http://et791.ni.utoledo.edu/~gaugsbu/asg4/asg4.2.html

Comment: It would help readability if you indent your code with 2 or 4 spaces (not tabs). If you're using jQuery, you should include a jQuery tag.

Answer (score -1):

Rules for [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) are pretty simple. You have to delegate events to an element/document that is a permanent asset and target the elements that are dynamic.

You can't store `$listItems` since that collection won't include new ones added after code is run.

It seems your `<ul>` is permanent so do something like:

```
$('ul').on('mouseover click', 'li', function(event){
  // do stuff
}).on('mouseout','li', function(event){
   // do stuff
})
```